# Oracle SQL: join between values in a view

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a view which shows a list of gsmnumbers, which is used to calculate certain tariffs. These numbers come from a number table, and it's a simple and basic view. 
However, I need to add more numbers to it based on specific data, and that it is where it becomes difficult.

I have a table which is not a list of gsmnumbers, but just contains a few ranges. I need to be able to get all the numbers within those ranges added to the gsmnumber view.

If we look at the table which contains the ranges, they have an ID, a product code, a beginvalue and endvalue (beginvalue and endvalue need to be included as well). I need to have a list of all number values that are between the beginvalues and endvalues for each row where the product code is 37.

The fact that I have different ranges makes it difficult for me to find an answer to this, as most searches of mine just answer how to get values of a single range.

Comment: You need something like a left join with a compound condition, like `... from gsmtable g left join rangetable r on ( g.gsmnumber >= r.beginvalue AND g.gsmnumber <= r.endvalue) ... where r.productCode = 37`. In case the numbers are of a number datatype, `... from gsmtable g left join rangetable r on ( g.gsmnumber between r.beginvalue AND r.endvalue ) ...where r.productCode = 37`

Comment: Perhaps if you updated your question to include sample input and expected output data, we would be able to help you? See [this question](for an example of how sample data has been provided) - that's the very minimum that should be provided - create table and insert statements would be appreciated, or if you can set up a query using the WITH clause to generate sample data, that would be even better. Or provide a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with the scripts contained there.

Answer (score 0):

You could build simple hierarchical query returning numbers (1,2,3,4...)  and join it with your table:

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/10b06/1)</sup>

```
with 
  tmp1 as (select max(endvalue-beginvalue+1) mv from gsm where product=37),
  tmp2 as (select level lvl from tmp1 connect by level<=mv)
select id, beginvalue+lvl-1 nr, beginvalue, endvalue
  from gsm join tmp2 on beginvalue+lvl-1<=endvalue
  where product = 37 order by id, beginvalue+lvl-1
```